# nginx latest version with stream

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

I would like some clarifications regarding `nginx` installation at Ubuntu (22.04.3). I need to install `stream` module and expect latest version (current: 1.24, Apr-2023).

My current attempts are shown below. What should I do to achieve my goal?

**Current attempts**

a) Install `nginx-full` from Ubuntu repo: I get older version 1.18 (Apr-2020) with `stream`.

b) Add official nginx repo: I get "regular" nginx 1.24 (without `stream`).

c) Add official nginx repo: I get `nginx-full` but on older version 1.18 (don't know how to check this but I'm assuming it came from Ubuntu repo, therefore same case as "a" above).

d) Download and compile `nginx --with-stream`: facing issues with ports below 1024 (80, 443, 25, 587...) and user not root.

**Additional clarification:**

Regarding topic "d", see below content of `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service`. I did also try replacing `www-data` with `nginx` (from `adduser --system --no-create-home --disabled-login --group nginx`) with no success either.

```
[Unit]
Description=Nginx HTTP Server
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
ExecStop=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s quit
ExecReload=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx.pid
User=www-data
Group=www-data
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```